# python-jira unable to return JIRA object key

Tags: python-2.7, jira, python-jira

I am working on a tool for Jira using the python-jira library.

```
def find_ticket_key_by_name(search_string):
    global jira
    result = jira.search_issues('project=FSA and status != Done  and summary ~ "HOST TESTER-APP:SERVICE1-SERVICECOUNT" order by createdDate', maxResults=1)
    return result
```

The function above successfully returns a jira object

```
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'FSA-11', id=u'119060'>]
```

however if I attempt to print the key value

```
result.key
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'ResultList' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem and posting solution in case somebody gets stuck like me.

In my case I am only returning one result and I assumed it will return one object.

This is not the case as indicated by the "ResultList" error. Even if you return 1 result the function will still return a list with 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is a List in python, so try the following:-

- **result[0].key** to get the key value
- **result[0].id** to get id value.

You can always check type any data using **type** keyword, in your case it will be **class 'jira.client.ResultList'** which is a List object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the key of issue you searched,

```py
if result:
  for issue in result:
    print(issue.key)
```

It should help.